# UISlider values

Tags: objective-c, uislider

I'm trying to create an app that has three UISlider used for selecting R, G and B values. The slider should change the colour of a label according to the sliders values.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
NSInteger color;

IBOutlet UISlider *redSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *greenSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *blueSlider;
IBOutlet UILabel  *colorLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *redSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *greenSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *blueSlider;

colorLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: redSlider.value green:greenSlider.value
blue:blueSlider.value alpha:1];


 @end
```

ViewController.m

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()


 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@synthesize redSlider, greenSlider, blueSlider;




@end
```

This is what I have so far and I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Why have you got the `ivars` and the `syntheszie` you do know all these are generated automatically because of the `property`? And what exactly is your question????

Comment: I've used this as an example. I'm a total newbie, so basically I have no idea what the hell I'm doing. http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/24603-uicolor-with-rgb-sliders.html

Comment: You can't bind values like that in iOS. You need to listen for the change of values and then set the colour at the point at which they change.

Comment: What are the maximums for the sliders? If it is 255, you need to divide by 255 when you are using them to set rgb values. If it is 1, it should be functioning. Try using the tintColor property of the label.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this like...

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

// you need to make sure these are actually created
// and give them all a target of self and action sliderValueChanged
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *redSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *greenSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *blueSlider;

// not sure where this is set up
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *colorLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // You may have to create your labels and sliders in here...
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)sliderValueChanged
{
    // the sliders have changed so set the colour of the label
    // based on the new values of the sliders.
    self.colorLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:self.redSlider.value
                                                green:self.greenSlider.value
                                                 blue:self.blueSlider.value
                                                alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can i know where are you calling sliderValueChanged method?

Comment: @Popeye Hello again... thanks for the needless down vote. As explained in my answer in the comments where I have declared the properties for the sliders. The sliders need to have targets set to call the `sliderValueChanged` method. I didn't know if the OP was using a nib or code to set the view up so I didn't want to assume. Which is why I also put a comment in the `viewDidLoad` method to say that the sliders and label may need setting up here too. If you have any constructive criticism then I welcome it. If not please stop down voting for no reason.

Comment: sorry to say but you must read the 1st two lines of the question that mentioned I'm trying to create an app that has three UISlider used for selecting R, G and B values. The slider should change "the colour of a label" according to the sliders values.the color of the label and you are changing its Text color.So, please don’t say needless down vote.

Comment: @Popeye It is needless. The sliders should **change** the colour of the label. The only way they will **change** the colour of the label is if the sliders have a target method that gets called when the value of the sliders is **changed**. My answer is the only answer that will **change** anything. Your answer will just set the colour once. When the sliders are moved nothing will happen. You clearly haven't understood either the question or my answer. Please stop down voting due to lack of understanding.

Comment: Sorry I think i understood better the question what he has asked and you just give him an answer which revolves near by his requirement not the exact solution.

Comment: Can users please note that the user `Popeye` in this discussion isn't myself it was `Stark` who has since changed his username from `Popeye` too `Stark`, I myself have no issue with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't actually have a question I'm going to take a guess that your code doesn't compile, because it wouldn't.

```
colorLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: redSlider.value green:greenSlider.value blue:blueSlider.value alpha:1];
```

The above line doesn't belong in you interface. I would recommend you change the code you currently have to something like.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// You don't need the ivars anymore these get generated with the properties below  

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *redSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *greenSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *blueSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *colorLabel
@property (assign) NSInteger color;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

// Also no need for the synthesize as these also get generated automatically

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // To change the actual color when changing the value of a slider move this to a method that gets called on slider changed.
    colorLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:self.redSlider.value green:self.greenSlider.value self.blue:blueSlider.value alpha:1];
}

@end
```

And once you actually ask a question I might also be able to help you with that.

Comment: This won't allow the user to change the colour of the label by sliding the sliders which is what I think is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewController.h :-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{    
IBOutlet UISlider *redSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *greenSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *blueSlider;
IBOutlet UILabel  *colorLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *redSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *greenSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *blueSlider;

 @end
```

and your ViewController.m will be like this:-

#import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()
 @end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize redSlider, greenSlider, blueSlider;
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self changeLabelColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(Void) changeLabelColor
    {
colorLabel.backgroundcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:redSlider.value green:redSlider.value blue:redSlider.value alpha:1.0];
     }
        @end
```

As i didn’t copied paste and i have written it, there might be some typo..
textcolor wouldn’t change label color so i changed it to backgroundcolor.
you can also add slider method with IBAction.